# Android local notification sometime won't show

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-annotations

I want to make local notifications that appears only 1st, 2nd and 3rd day of the month at for example 11am. I set up my notifications for 3 days in row at 12:30, 14:30 and 18:30 but it shown only once, at 14:30.
When I checked android monitor for that hour it looks like android just skip that sec?! 
Here is my code:

here is my service which is setup in main activity in onCreate

```
`@EService
public class NotifiService extends Service {
public int counter = 0;

public NotifiService(Context applicationContext) {
    super();
    Log.w("here!", "here i am");
}
public NotifiService(){

}




@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    Log.i("-----b", "onStartCommand");

    startTimer();


    return Service.START_STICKY; //super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent broadCastIntent = new Intent("com.Yyyyy.Xxxxx.Yyyyy.BootBro");
    sendBroadcast(broadCastIntent);
    stopTimerTask();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Background
public void checkDate(){
    Log.w("f", "if working");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int  d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int h = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int s = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int m = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    if( d==17 || d == 18 || d == 19){
        if (h == 12 || h == 14 || h == 16) {

            if (m == 30) {
                 if (s == 30) {


                Log.w("notify", "working>>>>");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity_.class);
                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());

                    b.setAutoCancel(false)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_icon)
                            .setTicker("FabReminder")
                            .setContentTitle("FabReminder")
                            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification))
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                    //.setContentInfo("Tap this bar and select shop");


                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask;
long oldTime=0;
public void stopTimerTask(){
    if (timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}
public void initializeTimerTask(){
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            checkDate();
        }
    };
}
public void startTimer(){
    timer = new Timer();
    initializeTimerTask();
    timer.schedule(timerTask,1000,1000);
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Log.w("killed task >>>"," task killed");
    Intent broadCastIntent = new Intent("com.Yyyyy.Xxxxx.Yyyyy.BootBro");
    sendBroadcast(broadCastIntent);
}`
```

Here is my BroadcastReceiver:

`public class BootBro extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public int MID;

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //context.startService(new Intent(context, NotifiService_.class));
    Log.w(BootBro.class.getSimpleName(), "Service stops!");
 context.startService(new Intent(context, NotifiService_.class));


}
```

}`

and AndroidManifest

```
`<service android:name="com.Yyyyy.Xxxx.Yyyyy.NotifiService_" android:enabled="true"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.Yyyyy.Xxxx.Yyyy.BootBro" android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped">

        <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">

        </action>
            <action android:name="com.Yyyyy.Xxxx.Yyyy.BootBro"/>
         </intent-filter>
    </receiver>`
```

Comment: Do you mind to do it with different way?

Comment: I think your option sounds great, Thanks a lot. I will check it today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach you can setup easy with a **AlarmManager**.

*This class provides access to the system alarm services.These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future...* [More](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Alarms have these characteristics:

- They let you fire Intents at set times and/or intervals.
- You can use them in conjunction with broadcast receivers to start services and perform other operations.
- They operate outside of your application, so you can use them to trigger events or actions even when your app is not running, and even if the device itself is asleep.
- They help you to minimize your app's resource requirements. You can schedule operations without relying on timers or continuously running background services

The official Android documentation have a tutorial that you can follow [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

And also here is an example with a [simple app](https://github.com/williamgdev/RepeatingAlarm/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mac/fireflies/wgt/repeatingalarm/AlarmService.java) that you can setup an alarm to wake up.